Undesired Padding Below FAB in Android 15 Due to WindowInsets Handling Changes – How to Fix?
Undesired Padding Below FAB in Android 15 Due to WindowInsets Handling Changes – How to Fix?
Starting with Android 15, the handling of WindowInsets has changed, and I'm encountering an issue that wasn’t present in Android 14 or below. Specifically, in my case, there is undesired padding or margin below the Floating Action Button (FAB). This issue occurs when my app is run on Android 15 but not on earlier versions. floatingActionButton is a property of androidx.compose.material3.Scaffold.
What I’ve observed:

The Floating Action Button (FAB) appears to have extra padding at the bottom on Android 15.
There are no layout changes in the XML, and no programmatic changes to padding or margins between versions.
I believe this may be related to how Android 15 handles insets, particularly when using views that require interoperability between new and old versions of WindowInsets.

Example:

FAB on Android 14 and below: Looks as expected with no extra padding.
FAB on Android 15: Has extra padding at the bottom, pushing it up from the edge of the screen.

Screenshot on Android 15:

What I’ve tried:

I’ve verified the layout XML for the FAB and ensured that no padding or margins are explicitly set.
I've checked my code for any programmatic changes to padding or margins and haven’t found any.
I’ve tried applying the setPadding() and setMargin() methods programmatically to compensate for the extra space, but this didn’t resolve the issue.
I’ve looked into handling WindowInsetsCompat but still haven’t found the right approach.

Question:
How can I remove this undesired padding/margin below the Floating Action Button on Android 15, while keeping the layout consistent across Android 14 and earlier versions?

You can remove the undesired padding by specifying the contentWindowInsets parameter in the Scaffold composable, like this:
Scaffold(
  modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
  floatingActionButton = { /* FloatingActionButton here */ },
  contentWindowInsets = WindowInsets.navigationBars.only(WindowInsetsSides.Horizontal)
) { innerPadding ->
   // Scaffold content here
}

This approach restricts the insets to only apply horizontal padding, preventing any vertical padding that would otherwise affect the FloatingActionButton. It's useful in cases where you want precise control over the insets. You can read more about WindowInsets here and WindowInsetsSides here.
However, be mindful that this solution works best in specific situations where vertical insets are unnecessary. If your layout relies on full window insets for other elements, be cautious of the potential impact this adjustment may have.

life saver answer... my whole jetpack compose app's appbars of every screen had strange padding on top. I used this and it worked. thanks
